# Angular 2 - Get component instance

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-template

I have two components like these:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'comp1',
    template: `<h1>{{ custom_text }}</h2>`
})
export class Comp1 {
    custom_text:string;
    constructor(text:string) {
        this.custom_text = text;
    }
}

/*********************************************/

@Component({
    selector: 'comp2',
    directives: [Comp1],
    template: `
    <b>Comp 2</b>
    <comp1></comp1>
    `
})
export class Comp2 {
    constructor() {
        // ...
        // How to send my own text to comp1 from comp2
        // ...
    }
}
```

Is it possible to send my own text from `comp1` to `comp2`?

Is it possible to get the `comp1` instance from `comp2`?

Comment: Check this out http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/01/23/angular2-viewchildren-contentchildren-difference-viewproviders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is very easy to accomplish that,

Checkout the Tutorial : [MULTIPLE COMPONENTS](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html)
Part 3 of the Angular2 Tutorials to see how to send inputs.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'comp1',
    template: `<h1>{{customText}}</h2>`,
    inputs: ['customText']
})
export class Comp1 {
    public customText:string;
    constructor(text:string) {
        this.customText= text;
    }

 // ngOnChange to make sure the component is in sync with inputs changes in parent
 ngOnChanges() {
       this.customText= text;
    }
}

/*********************************************/

@Component({
    selector: 'comp2',
    directives: [Comp1],
    template: `
    <b>Comp 2</b>
    <comp1 customText = "My Custom Test"></comp1>
    `
})
export class Comp2 {
    constructor() {
    }
}
```

Try it out and let me know how it went.

Comment: Doesn't this throw an error?: `constructor(text:string) {`

Comment: Yep. But was just a example.

Comment: @Jon..., thanks, yes your original example had the issue.  I was wondering/asking why Chibi didn't show a working solution.  (So that future readers don't try to cut and paste the solution, only to find out it doesn't work.)

Answer (score 5):

comp2 is the parent of comp1, so

- to send data from child to parent (comp1 to comp2) add an [OutputProperty](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#inputs-outputs) to the child:
   `@Output() someEvent = newEventEmitter();` 
  and `emit()` an event on it: `this.someEvent.emit('some text');`
    The parent will need to bind to the output property/event: `<comp2 (someEvent)="someHandler()"></comp2>`
- to get a reference to an instance of a child component (comp2 gets an reference to comp1), use [`@ViewChild`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ViewChild-var.html) or [`@Query`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Query-var.html) in comp2: `@ViewChild(Comp1) viewChild:comp1;`  You can then access `this.comp1` in `ngAfterViewInit()`, or later in the component's lifecycle.

Comment: I started to think it was an Output case as well but if you look at his code he is trying to do an input case and expressed it wrongly. I like your answer on the emitters but normally I see that Outputs make the component hard to change as we need to maintain the call back contracts, I normally change a change in the backend to save and propagate change but for minimal state data a callback is fine.